# HTML/JS Form with calculations then output result as PDF

Tags: javascript, forms

I would like to make a form in HTML where a user enters some data, and via JS that data is used to calculate results that are output to result fields in real time.  By that I mean that say I enter Age (24) and Height (1.82m), a field will automatically display the result of 24 * 1.82 after the 1.82 is typed.

Also I would like to know how to output a web page as PDF.

Comment: Did you actually do **any** research before writing your question ?

Comment: yes i did, however the only part I was stumped on was displaying calculation results in realtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question :

```
function calc() {
   var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('field1').value);
   var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('field2').value);
   document.getElementById('total').value = a * b;
}
```

This gets the values from 2 fields (`field1` and `field2`), multiplies them together and then updates the `value` of the `total` input. Example HTML used with the above would be :

```
<input id="field1" onblur="calc()" value="24" />
<input id="field2" onblur="calc()" value="1.82" />
<input id="total" value="" />
```

the `onblur` attribute calls the specified function (`calc()`) when the `input` looses focus. Note that this is a very simple example and contains no error checking (ie there is a number present etc)

Second question :

For creating PDFs from HTML [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is the best I have used - its simple to use and has lots of wrappers for different languages (server side - not client side). It runs as a standalone application too (on a server). Oh and its free !

Answer (score 0):

You will have to input fields, add an event listener that is being triggered when the content changes and then simply fill the "result" input with the result. With the use of jQuery this will be very simple.

For generating pdf's in Javascript take a look at this libary:

- http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/